# Centos hardware support

Tags: centos, centos5

I'm wanting to setup centos on a local machine. What hardware can I buy so I *know* it will work when installing?

Are there some standard configs that just work?

Do some hardware brands work better than others - seems HP drivers are often in the kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Red Hat maintains [a database of formally-supported hardware](https://hardware.redhat.com/) which is the ultimate authority.  In my experience, any reputable component vendor that's not too cutting-edge is likely to be fine.  I particularly look for Intel motherboards, graphics cards and NIC chipsets, because they work pretty well with the free-software community.

Weird motherboards intended for gamers, with high-end graphics cards, tend not to work at all well.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that it's slightly hypocritical to answer a question **and** vote to close it.  I regretted my vote once it was done, and thought that actually it wasn't a silly question after all; but there seems to be no way to recant a vote to close even if there haven't yet been enough votes to do so.  Sorry.

Comment: I think you can vote to reopen, but one vote does not a close question make. Others agreed with your initial vote, so don't feel bad.

Comment: Bart: that's a much appreciated reality check - thank you!

Comment: This was closed as it's an unusual thing - to setup a local server perhaps? This is how programmers often test their code, it saves transmitting the files to the repos and deploying to a web server before testing - I imagine this to be a very common use of a web server, certainly is amongst the programmers I know.